Subscribe form as part of a login modal not opening
    <div class="modal login fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header border-0">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login/New Registration/Subscribers</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-02 justify-content-center" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#login" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="false"> <span>Login</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#register" role="tab" aria-controls="register" aria-selected="true"><span>Advertise</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab2" name="register-tab2" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#subscribe" role="tab" aria-controls="register" aria-selected="true"><span>Subscribe</span></a>
          </li>

        </ul>
<!-- Business login Only -->        
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab">
            <form class="row mt-4 align-items-center" action="/" name="Login_Form" id="Login_Form">
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LoginEmailAddress" id="LoginEmailAddress" placeholder="Enter Email Address (needed if forgot login credentials)">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="LoginPassword" id="LoginPassword" placeholder="Enter Password or (leave blank if forgot)">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 d-grid">
                <button type="submit" name="Proceed" id="Proceed" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="JavaScript: return ValidateLogin(this.id);">Proceed</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 d-grid">
                <button type="submit" name="ForgottenPassword" id="ForgottenPassword" class="btn btn-info" onClick="JavaScript: return ValidateLogin(this.id);">Forgot Password</button>
              </div>              </form>
            <div class="login-social-media border ps-4 pe-4 pb-4 pt-0 mt-5">

              <form class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <img alt="Business Directory Security" longdesc="Business Directory Security" src="/images/gdpr.png" width="100%">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
<!-- Business Registration Only -->            
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="register" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="register-tab">
            <form class="row mt-4 mb-5 align-items-center" method="post" action="/" name="Advertiser_Form" id="Advertiser_Form">
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="AdvertisersName" id="AdvertisersName" placeholder="Enter First and Last Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="AdvertisersEmailAddress" id="AdvertisersEmailAddress" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="AdvertisersPassword" id="AdvertisersPassword" placeholder="Enter Password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="AdvertisersConfirmPassword" id="AdvertisersConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 d-grid">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="JavaScript: return ValidateAdvertiser();">Proceed</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="login-social-media border ps-4 pe-4 pb-4 pt-0 mt-5">

              <form class="row">
                <img alt="Business Directory Security" longdesc="Business Directory Security" src="/images/gdpr.png" width="100%">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
<!-- Subscribers Registration Only -->            
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="subscribe" name="subscribe" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="subsriber-tab">
                        
            <form class="row mt-4 mb-5 align-items-center" method="post" action="/" name="Subscriber_Form" id="Subscriber_Form">
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                  <%
                       If (Trim(SubscriberMsg) <> "") Then
                    %>
                            <h6 style="color: red">
                                <% Response.Write(SubscriberMsg) %>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </h6>                               
                    <%
                       End If
                    %>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="SubscribersEmailAddress" id="SubscribersEmailAddress" placeholder="Enter Email Address" value="<% Response.Write(Trim(TheSubscribersEmailAddress)) %>">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="SubscribersPassword" id="SubscribersPassword" placeholder="Enter Password" value="<% Response.Write(Trim(TheSubscribersPassword)) %>">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-3 col-sm-12">
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="SubscribersConfirmPassword" id="SubscribersConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="<% Response.Write(Trim(TheSubscribersConfirmPassword)) %>">
              </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 d-grid">
                    <input type="hidden" name="SubscriberButtonClicked" id="SubscriberButtonClicked" value="Yes">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="JavaScript: return ValidateSubscribe();" name="SubscriberButton" id"SubscriberButton">Proceed</button>
                </div>                          
            </form>
            <div class="login-social-media border ps-4 pe-4 pb-4 pt-0 mt-5">

              <form class="row">
                <img alt="Business Directory Security" longdesc="Business Directory Security" src="/images/gdpr.png" width="100%">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I have the above modal.
$('#loginModal').modal('show'); opens the main Modal showing the Login form. How do I get it to open the Subscribe Form instead please? Is it possible?
I nned to open it to show any error messages plus I will need to do the same to the Adveriser one afterwards. I could add the error message to the main login form but that will mean the user having to go to the correct form to redo the contents
Thanks
